# Error with Selenium when clicking a link

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

Please excuse the beginners question, but I was hoping I could get some practical help here after searching on Google for a while.

I am doing the following in C# Express 2010:

```
selenium.Click("link=Specimen Volume Report - Drugs");
```

The html source of what I am trying to click on is:

```
<a href="/Admin/Reports/SpecimenVolume.aspx?p=lKpZwTqT4/OMY6523drWvbTjKKs7Nu4Z">Specimen Volume Report - Drugs&nbsp;</a>
```

The error I am getting is:

```
LogIn.LogIn.Login:
Selenium.SeleniumException : ERROR: Element link=Specimen Volume Report - Drugs not found
```

What am I doing wrong? What information do you need from me to help?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `selenium` is a web driver I think you want:

`selenium.FindElement(By.LinkText("Specimen Volume Report - Drugs&nbsp;")).Click();`

You could potentially shorten the string by using `By.PartialLinkText("Report - Drugs")` too if you like that idea.

I'd recommend looking at the documentation at http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html, specifically **Locating UI Elements (WebElements)** to see the different ways you can find element(s).

Comment: thanks so much for your help. i dont think i have the web driver because i am unable to do selenium.FindElement

Answer (score 1):

You are getting error may be because of space at end of `Specimen Volume Report - Drugs&nbsp;`

You can try to go with different element locator, below i have mentioned one of them,

```
selenium.click("//a[contains(text(),"Specimen Volume Report")]")
```

Comment: can you please correct the code above. i think there's a parenthesis missing or something, i cannot get it to compile

Comment: selenium.click("//a[contains(text(),\"Specimen Volume Report\")]");  try this